# Show only parent categories and sub-categories in left nav

Tags: magento-1.9, category, catalog, navigation, category-tree

I have currently implemented a code which shows all categories on the left nav instead of that I want current category and current category's all sub categories.

Now my category structure is like

```
-parent1
 -sub 1
  -sub sub 1
 -sub 2
-parent2
 -sub 3
```

Now if i am on page Sub1 then I must be able to see all sub categories of sub 1 and also the sub categories of parent1
If I am on sub sub 1 then I must be able to see sub categories of sub1 .

I have currently implemented the following code

```
<!-- List all categories and their second level subcategories -->
<div class="block block-list block-categories">
    <div id="block-categories" class="block-title active">
        <strong><span>Categories </span></strong>
    </div>

<div id="leftnav" class="block-content" style="display:block">
    <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
        <ul id="leftnav-tree" class="level0">
            <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                <li class="level0<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                   <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></span></a>
                    <?php //if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>
                        <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                        <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level1">
                                <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                    <li class="level1<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                         <?php $secondLevelSubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                         <?php if (count($secondLevelSubcategories ) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $subcategory->getId() ?>" class="level2">
                                <?php foreach($secondLevelSubcategories as $secondLevelSubcategory ): ?>
                                    <li class="level2<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($secondLevelSubcategory )): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($secondLevelSubcategory ) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($secondLevelSubcategory ->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php //endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree', 'recursive')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I this code gives all categories including sub categories.

Answer (score 1):

if you are extend this class `class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`

then you can check with the function like below

```
if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
            $activeClass = ' class="cur-act-cat"';
        }
```

or if not you can add below two function to your block to check if category is active or not

```
     /**
     * Check whether specified category is active
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $category
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCategoryActive($category)
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()
            ? in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathIds()) : false;
    }

     /**
     * Check whether specified category is active
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $category
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isCategoryActive($category)
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()
            ? in_array($category->getId(), $this->getCurrentCategory()->getPathIds()) : false;
    }
```

hope this will sure help you

Comment: I am not getting where to add the code. Can you please point out where to add?

Comment: in your block or if your block is extend `class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` then no need for both function

Comment: Then what is the work around?
I the demo is installed on http://infigic.com/ds4u/
There click on any category then there will be a sidebar visible. but it shows all categories and sub categories

Comment: @Bhargav, you can download and see extensions code as reference to achieve your functionality. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-sidebar-navigation-2.html

i am not associated with this extension at any more.it is just for your help

Comment: Thanks @liyakat I am currently using that extension only to show sub categories